# Ubuntu hangs on purple screen after external HD install

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I am running ubuntu 11 on my home desktop, which was dual booted with Windows 7, and all was working great.

Today, I was trying to install Ubuntu 12 to an external USB hard drive. I put in my Ubuntu 12 disk, restarted, went through the install process setting up partitions on the external drive, etc etc. I am now having the hanging problem on the purple screen. This is whether or not the external HD is attached or not.

I tried to run a boot-repair disk with recommended settings, and that did not work. I can see everything in GRUB loader, just doesnt seem to want to get into ubuntu.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the GRUB loader, go to the Ubuntu entry and type 'e'. Then, remove the words: 'quiet splash vt_handoff=7' and replace with 'noquiet nosplash'. This should show you the kernel loading, so you can see where it freezes.